# Evernote App Notebook for iOS

Tags: ios, evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I want to create evernote book for My app using https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/app_notebook.php

I can not understand how to enable App Notebook for my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can open up a support ticket at https://dev.evernote.com/support and ask Evernote to enable App Notebook permissions on your API key (if you need an API key you can get one here: https://dev.evernote.com/#apikey).  Please note that you cannot have both a conventional create-only or full-access API and a App Notebook key with the same key.  You will need to create a new key if you require both a App Notebook key and a full-access/create-only key.